# What's port 1283?

Tags: windows-server-2008, port, tcp, networking

I see a lot of connection attempts to 1283/tcp on my firewall from a client computer to a Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller. What exactly is this traffic? Something to do with NetBIOS, perhaps?

Comment: I see there's a well-known service called ProductInfo on that port, but I can't find any useful description of that service either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a Shoretel VoIP application.

Answer (score 3):

According to [**IANA "registered" port list**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), maybe something called EWALL?  Other than that, I'd put Wireshark on it and see if if you can see anything from the packet side.

Although anything can use any port number (given permissions) so this is by no means an exhaustive list.

Comment: +1  You can't beat looking at the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) on the client to identify the application that is using the port.

(You could also use the built-in `netstat` command from a Command Prompt, but a GUI application like CurrPorts is far simpler in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

[IANA Ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers)  This list says it is

```
 productinfo     1283/tcp   Product Information 
 productinfo     1283/udp   Product Information
```